# How to convert dataframe in jpg format to csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, ocr, python-3.7

I receive some reports in pdf or jpg format. I did a code to parse dataframe in pdf to csv. Now I want to convert dataframe in jpg format to csv and then give expected structure.

Structure of file I receive:
https://pasteboard.co/IoxQnUZa.jpg

I tried to ocr but i totally have no idea how to manage this task. Could you help me and give some tips?
When I try to use PIL and pytesseract like:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open('a.jpg')


text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

But get strange errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 184, in run_tesseract
>       proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "copy_version1.py", line 7,
>   in 
>       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 309, in image_to_string
>       }output_type   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 308, in 
>       Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 218, in run_and_get_output
>       run_tesseract(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 186, in run_tesseract
>       raise TesseractNotFoundError() pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not
>   installed or it's not in your path

I expect to have dataframe in csv, then I will manage file to give expected structure.

Comment: what did you do to parce the data from PDF? If that by chance using OCR as well?

Comment: I used tabula-py to read dataframe from pdf and store it in pandas df to manage columns etc.